# Javascript in PHP called through AJAX not happening

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yui

I am using a YUI Rich Text Editor and saving the entered text into a database. Since the user can enter several different texts, I am using a drop down to let them choose an existing database entry to edit, or create a new one. To do this I call a JS function that handles AJAX, use that to get the information from the database, and then display the returned information.

The PHP code that is called is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
alert('HEY HEY HEY'); //Just to see if JS is happening at all
document.getElementById('saveName').innerHTML = '$data[name]';
document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = '$data[content]';
document.getElementById('editID').value = '$data[id]';
</script>";
```

When I change the select box no errors are thrown, and Firebug reports that the AJAX was successful (POST 200 OK) and the response is what I expect:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
alert('HEY HEY HEY');
document.getElementById('saveName').innerHTML = 'Default';
document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = 'REALLY LARGE BLOB OF TEXT';
document.getElementById('editID').value = '1';
</script>
```

But the alert never happens and the inner HTML doesn't change. Can you not call javascript like this from a PHP page loaded by AJAX?

Comment: Try removing the `<script></script>` tags from your response text. Shouldn't be necessary if you're evaluating the return on ajax callback.

Comment: What's the JS that handles the AJAX request and response look like?

Comment: Also, on `eval()`, your line breaks will probably throw an error `unterminated string literal` - remove the line breaks in your response before you return it.

Comment: Removing the script tags just prints the js out to the screen like plain text, but it did point out where the problem was. My AJAX function posts the response text in the innerHTML of a div (div.innerHTML = responseText) It seems as if the browser doesn't interpret javascript added after the page is loaded, looks like I'll just have to create a different AJAX function for this page

Comment: Instead of using `innerHTML`, you should `eval(responseText)` to perform your desired actions.

Comment: For instance `if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { eval(xmlhttp.responseText); }` (that is, if `xmlhttp` is your XMLHttpRequest handle).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$json = array('data' => "$data");
echo json_encode($json);
```

Then on the call back page (assuming jquery):

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "someurl.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {            
            $('#saveName').innerHTML = data.name;
            $('#editor').innerHTML = data.content;
            $('#editID').value = data.value;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load stuff into the DOM dynamically with PHP/AJAX/Whatever. What you can't do is to modify HTML elements dynamically loaded in to the DOM without running some soft of LiveQuery (like the live command in jquery). However, sometimes the execution of dynamically loaded stuff from javascript simply wont work.

In which context do you load this script? It may work do define functions who's loaded at runtime, then you simply call them with your php generated code.

In example, put this inside your head tag

```
<script>
function sendAlert(input) {
   alert(input);
}

function changeInnerHtml(id,innerContent) {
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = innerContent;
}

function changeInnerValue(id,innerValue) {
   document.getElementById(id).value = innerValue;
}
</script>
```

And try to change your php code to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<script>
sendAlert('HEY HEY HEY'); 
changeInnerHtml('saveName', '$data[name]');
changeInnerHtml('editor', '$data[content]');
changeInnerValue('editID', '$data[id]');
</script>";
```

Not sure if it will resolve your problem but it might be worth a try :)